# Refresh a DIV when select another date from jQueryUI Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am doing a one-page application. My page has three sections. In the first section I use jQuery inline calendar. I placed a `div` in the second where I am generating dynamic input fields when I click on the button which is presented in the third section.

When I click on another date I add an input field dynamically, and I want to refresh the input field section and keep the selected date.

Comment: Add sample code to know your issue shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This should make it working as expected.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                var selectedDate = $(this).val();
                $('#textBox_in_seconddiv').val(selectedDate);
            }
});
```